# Setting up a VT host

Tags: terminal

My recent project involves connecting to a remote machine using VT100 client from my .net application. I am new to developments around SSH, and VT. Currently I am evaluating couple of APIs to connect and interact with VT host. The problem is I cannot connect to the host any where out of office and even in office I get limited time slot. So in order to speed up my developments I want to setup a VT host and work with it. Can some one guide me how can I setup a VT host over a Windows or Linux VM.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found FreeSSH that can setup a secure shell host in Windows.